# Access Task Queue from GCE via cUrl

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'am trying to assess my GAE Task Queue from an GCE instant in the same project.
I have started the instant with the correct scoop and billing is enabled:

```
"serviceAccounts": [
{
  "email": "949416733789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue"
  ]
}
```

]

And i can generate an access token via this curl command:

```
curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

But when I try to curl to get the tasks using this curl I get an 403:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta2/projects/propane-****/taskqueues/default/tasks" -H "Authorization":"Bearer ya29.lABIrcEaJi0ItloNb62Lg_***************"
```

Generates this output

```
"error": {
"errors": 
[
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
```

Comment: It's looking like you are not authenticated in your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was using the default taskqueue, apparently that dose not work.
Changes the taskqueue name to demo, and it all works.